# Android ViewModel with SavedState rewrites arguments for new instances

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-savedstate, viewmodel-savedstate

I have an app which is having Master/Detail kind of architecture. When I select some item, the details are displayed in details fragment.

For the detail fragment to know what to load `id` is sent over via `Arguments`. Using `SavedStateHandle` in VM I can directly read these arguments from the handle without re-routing it in `Fragment` itself. That works great for the first detail fragment. The problem comes with next selections.

Every time I load details, the `id` from first selection is populated although every time a **new fragment is created** along with **new ViewModel**.

I was looking into the code of lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate library *(v.2.3.1)* and found this method in `SavedStateHandle` called:

```
static SavedStateHandle createHandle(@Nullable Bundle restoredState,
        @Nullable Bundle defaultState) {
    if (restoredState == null && defaultState == null) {
        return new SavedStateHandle();
    }

    Map<String, Object> state = new HashMap<>();
    if (defaultState != null) {
        for (String key : defaultState.keySet()) {
            state.put(key, defaultState.get(key));
        }
    }

    if (restoredState == null) {
        return new SavedStateHandle(state);
    }

    ArrayList keys = restoredState.getParcelableArrayList(KEYS);
    ArrayList values = restoredState.getParcelableArrayList(VALUES);
    if (keys == null || values == null || keys.size() != values.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid bundle passed as restored state");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        state.put((String) keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    return new SavedStateHandle(state);
}
```

Here I can see that in `defaultState` **the correct id** is set for every new view model. But as you can see `defaultState` is processed first and `restoredState` is processed after that. `restoredState` contains **same key with old `id`** which at the end replace the correct one from `defaultState`.

I can understand that is probably wanted behavior for real restoring but in my case I'm not restoring the fragment. Yes, the class is same but I'm just replacing detail fragment with another detail fragment with new/different data.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I give the framework a hint that this is not restoration and I'm not interested in saved values from old fragment?

Comment: If you are creatung a brand new fragment and therefore getting a new ViewModel, then `restoredState` would be null. What makes you think it isn't null?

Comment: Debugging? I can see it's not null. Also saveInstanceState should by definition save state between instances so I'm not surprised. But in this case it's not really desired behavior.

Comment: A brand new Fragment and a ViewModel associated work a brand new Fragment has no saved state. Please include how you create your brand new Fragment and how you create your ViewModel

Comment: Ok found out what was causing it! Thanks for pointing out to Fragment creation, looking into it deeper I found the culprit. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't mentioned was that I'm using `ViewPager2` for Master/Detail view. I didn't consider it having some influence on state staving but it has.

`ViewPager2` library is saving and restoring state on the background which is then used by `SavedStateHandle`. To map fragments with states it uses ids from `FragmentStateAdapter`. I didn't override `getItemId` method so ids were assigned by position.

This of course map same state to new fragments on the exact position. Implementing `getItemId` which assign different ids to different instances of fragment fixed the problem.